# Too many values in a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

The following is the homework question: For each student name, list the course numbers(s), the student took, where the student obtained the lowest grade..

I keep getting too many values errors

The SQL I wrote:

```
SELECT DISTINCT student.student_id, std_name
FROM student 
WHERE (student.student_id) IN 
(SELECT enrollment.student_id, course#, MIN(grade) 
FROM enrollment
GROUP BY enrollment.student_id);
```

I haven't been able to do any subquery with multiple columns

```
SELECT DISTINCT student.student_id, std_name
FROM student 
WHERE (student.student_id) IN 
(SELECT enrollment.student_id, course#, MIN(grade) 
FROM enrollment
GROUP BY enrollment.student_id);
```

> ORA-00913: too many values
>   00913. 00000 -  "too many values"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 18 Column: 2

Comment: The question is ambiguous.  It is not clear if the "lowest" grade is the lowest grade for the student or for the class.

Answer (score 1):

You IN query should match the columns in you WHERE statement.

```
SELECT A.student_id, A.std_name, B.course#, B.min_grade
FROM student A
    INNER JOIN
        ( SELECT student_id, course#, MIN(grade) AS min_grade
          FROM enrollment
          GROUP BY student_id, course#
        ) B
        ON A.student_id = B.student_id
ORDER BY student_id
```

Comment: I still need to get (course#) and and the MIN (grade) in the sub query.

Comment: You need to user INNER JOIN to it. Let me modify my answer.

Comment: Getting a not a GROUP BY expression. error.  Here's the table info if that helps:

Comment: student_id        VARCHAR2(25)          NOT NULL,
  std_name          VARCHAR2(25)          NOT NULL,
  home_phone        CHAR(12)              NOT NULL,
  total_credits     NUMBER                NOT NULL,
  gpa               NUMBER(10,2)          NOT NULL,
  advisor_id        VARCHAR2(25)          NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT student_pk
    PRIMARY KEY (student_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (advisor_id) REFERENCES FACULTY(faculty_id)

Comment: course#           CHAR(12)              NOT NULL,
  student_id        VARCHAR2(25)          NOT NULL,
  grade             NUMBER(10,2)          NOT NULL,
 
  CONSTRAINT enrollment_pk PRIMARY KEY (course#,Student_id),
     FOREIGN KEY (course#) REFERENCES COURSE(course#)

Comment: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 18 Column: 41

Comment: SELECT enrollment.student_id, course#, MIN(grade) AS min_grade is line 18

Comment: I updated it a while ago I add course# in the group by clause.

Comment: Thank you for your patience.  This got me closer.

Comment: Please accept this as your answer if this helps you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, the `enrollment` table has a list of grades for each student in each course and you want a result set of the student with the lowest grade in each course. I think this is what you want:

```
    SELECT s.student_id, s.std_name, e.course#,min_grade
       FROM students s  LEFT JOIN enrollment e ON s.student_id = e.student_id
       LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT course#, MIN(grade) as min_grade from enrollment GROUP BY course#) mg
        ON e.course# = mg.course#
        WHERE e.grade = mg.min_grade
```

I hope I didn't make a typo in the table names.

By the way: I don't know if using `course#` as a column name was given with the assignment, but I wouldn't recommend using the hash character in table/column names. It is used to indicate a temporary table in SQL Server.

Comment: By the way, if more than one student has the same low grade for a course, then you will see all students with that grade in the result set.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put a multiple column sub-query in "in clause"!!!
The following shows all students which have taken at least one course and their min marks.

```
Select student_id, std_name, course#,  min (grade) as min_grade
From student inner join enrollment using (student_id)
group by student_id, std_name,course
```